# How to add a window global variable in module.export in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, export

I have a window global variable `gvar` that is defined in the file `client.js` and it contains many methods. I added 2 attributes to this variable in another `.js` file: `mymodule.js` in the following way :

`mymodule.js`:

```
window.gvar.usersList=[];
window.gvar.counter=0;

function moduleFunc1(arg){
//some code here
}
function moduleFunc2(){
//some code here
}
```

Now , I want to export `mymodule.js`,so I added this to `mymodule.js`:

```
module.exports={ window.gvar , moduleFunc1 , moduleFunc2 };
```

but I got problem with `window.gvar` ,it marks the dot sign in it and tells that a `:` is expected .

what am I messing ? How can I fix this ? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Name your property. With single name like `moduleFunc1` it can autodetect the property name, but with `window.gvar` syntax it can do. So you need to explicitly name your parameter.

```
module.exports={ gvar: window.gvar , moduleFunc1 , moduleFunc2 };
```